# jQuery change input to text, change back to password

Tags: jquery, input, passwords, show

I'm trying to show a password in an input field when I hover my mouse over it and after 1 second change it back to password.

This is what I have:

```
if (this.type === 'password') {
  this.type = "text";
  setTimeout(function () {
    this.type = "password";
  }, 100)
}
```

It changes the password to text, but doesn't change it back.
I'm trying to do it this way to stop the code changing all text fields to passwords.

Any idea how I can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: `this` inside your timeout is not what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not realised that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
if (this.type === 'password') {
  this.type = "text";
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    that.type = "password";
  }, 1000)
 }
```

Hold the `this` reference into a variable & use it inside `setTimeout`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you that explains what I was missing and it works.